# Symfony2 chain_provider in_memory users log in "bad credentials"

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have one hard coded admin user and the rest users coming from database. When I login with db users, it works, but if I login with hard coded admin user, it shows "Bad credentials" error. Here is a part of my security.yml file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Valoran\DrushBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost:      15

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [in_memory, user_db]
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                foo: { password: test }
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Acme\DrushBundle\Entity\User, property: userName }
```

Comment: in `firewall` section are your setting `provider` parameter with `providers` value ?

Comment: I set my firewall provider parameter to "chain_provider" and when I now log in, it shows: "No encoder has been configured for account "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User".  Where should I configure an encoder for it?

Comment: Ohh, sorry. I am silly, forgot to include         Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: and its encoder. Thank mate, you helped me :)

Comment: it would have been really great if you added your answer to help others??

Comment: @Baig I added the answer because I had the same problem and I know not everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, I'm adding the answer to make it more visible to others.
If you get

> No encoder has been configured for account
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User" chain provider

You need to add the encoder like it's shown below (for the database users and the users in memory)[security.yml]

```
security:
    encoders:
        Splendonia\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode-as-base64: true
            iterations: 10
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

To use one or more providers. The docs are [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/security.html#using-multiple-user-providers) and it looks like this:

```
providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, main]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    guest:  { password: guest, roles: [ 'ROLE_GUEST' ] }
        main:
            entity: { class: Splendonia\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: email }
```

Also remember to change the provider to chain_provider on firewalls, it looks something like this:

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: chain_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                default_target_path: /dashboard

            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

and that should do it.